# Can string functions be executed within a Select-Case statement?

Tags: .net, vb.net, select-case

In `VB.NET`, how can I achieve the following logic?

```
Select Case testString
    Case Contains("ABC") : Debug.Print "ABC"
    Case Contains("XYZ") : Debug.Print "XYZ"
    Case Else : Debug.Print "Other"
End Select
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply:

```
If testString.Contains("ABC") Then
    Debug.Print "ABC"
ElseIf testString.Contains("XYZ") Then
    Debug.Print "XYZ"
Else
    Debug.Print "Other"
End If
```

You cannot check this kind of function results in a Select Case statement, so using a simple If statement is your best and easier choice.

You can always do this:

```
Select Case True
    Case testString.Contains("ABC") : Debug.Print("ABC")
    Case testString.Contains("XYZ") : Debug.Print("XYZ")
    Case Else : Debug.Print("Other")
End Select
```

But it would work only in very concrete cases and is not very clear and necessary at all.

Answer (score 3):

In VB.NET you could use this [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Select Case True
    Case testString.Contains("ABC")
        Debug.Print("ABC")
    Case testString.Contains("XYZ")
        Debug.Print("XYZ")
    Case Else : Debug.Print("Other")
End Select
```

However, in this case i would prefer a simple `If` clause.

```
If testString.Contains("ABC") Then
    Debug.Print("ABC")
ElseIf testString.Contains("XYZ") Then
    debug.Print("XYZ")
Else
    Debug.Print("Other")
End If
```

This would be clearer and also compatible with C#. [`switch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) allows only constant expressions.

Comment: Since this works in this concrete example, it will not be a valid approach for functions which returns values different than just a Boolean type always.

Comment: @SysDragon: Of course you can not use `Select...Case` for everything. But in more cases than in C#. OP wants to use it with a function that returns `Boolean` anyway.